# Ubuntu/apache2: cannot open port 443

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install a SSL certificat on my Ubuntu 14 server (using apache 2). For some reason the port 443 appears to be closed

I installed and enable ssl

`/etc/apache2/ports.conf` is as followed:

```
Listen 80

#<IfModule ssl_module>
#       Listen 443
#</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
    NameVirtualHost 92.243.16.14:443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>



root@server01:/home/admin# netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10024         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1317/amavisd-new (m
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1184/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1116/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2037/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1116/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2037/apache2 



root@server01:/home/admin# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    9  1256 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 5874  654K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  247 14772 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
   31  1780 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
  120  7143 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 5937 1698K ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 5937 1698K ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  627 47626 ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  627 47626 ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  627 47626 ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  627 47626 ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
    0     0 ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
    0     0 ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    9  1256 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 5301 1649K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  627 47626 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
  627 47626 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: @MadHatter if I check online (for exemple: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) the port appear to be closed and I cannot install my ssl certificat

Comment: I agree that I can't telnet to port 443 on `92.243.16.14` whilst I can to ports 22 and 80.  Is this system perhaps behind some kind of NATting router, or does it actually possess that IP address?

Comment: @MadHatter yes that the server IP address. if I run curl -I https://localhost
I get: curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Comment: Could we see the output of `iptables -L -n -v` (you would need to cut-and-paste that into your question)?  Is this system behind any kind of hardware firewall?

Comment: I use ufw as firewall

Comment: I understand there is a *software* firewall involved, and my first question above leads to looking more closely at that.  I'm asking of there might be a *hardware* one *as well*.

Comment: I put the output of iptables -L -n -v as edit. I do not know if there is an hardware issue, it is a server I rent via a provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about `ufw`, but in this case I think it will be completely ineffective on `INPUT` traffic, because the rules that implement it come **after** a blanket `DROP` (the fifth rule in the `INPUT` chain).  You can see from the packet counts on the later rules in the `INPUT` chain that no packets are ever getting as far as any of the rules that are supposed to send traffic to the `ufw-` chains (which I presume are intended to implement `ufw` policy).

If you do

```
iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

that should open up your HTTPS port.  Making that persistent across reboots I leave to you, as it is implementation-dependent.

Comment: It working! you're great. Still struggling with my SSL installation but at least I have the port open. Have a nice day men

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the "accept".